# MySQL STR_TO_DATE gives invalid results?

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

I'm using MySQL 5.1.49 on Win64.  We're seeing the following behaviour on Solaris machines as well.  Here's my test table:

```
CREATE TABLE `date_test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date1` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Index_2` (`date1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

mysql> select * from date_test;
+----+---------------------+
| id | date1               |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2010-09-01 01:00:00 |
|  2 | 2010-09-06 23:59:59 |
|  3 | 2010-09-07 01:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following query runs correctly:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM date_test WHERE
           date1 > DATE_SUB('2010-10-06 23:59:59', interval 1 month);
+----+---------------------+
| id | date1               |
+----+---------------------+
|  3 | 2010-09-07 01:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, if I throw a `STR_TO_DATE()` in there, the query does not function as expected:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM date_test WHERE
         date1 > DATE_SUB(
            STR_TO_DATE('10/06/2010 23:59:59', '%m/%d/%Y %T'), interval 1 month
         );
+----+---------------------+
| id | date1               |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2010-09-01 01:00:00 |
|  2 | 2010-09-06 23:59:59 |
|  3 | 2010-09-07 01:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

There is very bizarre behaviour happening here.  You can use any date there with the `STR_TO_DATE()` function and that query will return all records in the table (something far in the future even).  The documentation indicates that `STR_TO_DATE()` should be returning a DATETIME, which should be a valid input to `DATE_SUB()`, but something is obviously amiss.

As a side note, running `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10/06/2010 23:59:59', '%m/%d/%Y %T')` returns the exact input of the first query, `2010-10-06 23:59:59`.  Also, if you wrap the results of the `STR_TO_DATE()` function in the problem query with the `TIMESTAMP()` function or a `CAST(STR_TO_DATE() AS DATETIME)`, then the results are returned as expected.  But should this really be necessary?

I'd like to think I'm missing something here.  Can anyone shed any light?

**UPDATE**

This is definitely looking like a bug.  On version 5.1.36:

```
-- interval of month or day does not work:
SELECT '1999-04-01 23:34:12' > DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('09/06/2010 23:59:59', '%m/%d/%Y %T'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
--->  1   (incorrect)
-- using 720 hours (30 days) works:
SELECT '1999-04-01 23:34:12' > DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('09/06/2010 23:59:59', '%m/%d/%Y %T'), INTERVAL 720 HOUR);
--->  0
-- wrapping in TIMESTAMP( ) works:
SELECT '1999-04-01 23:34:12' > DATE_SUB(TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('09/06/2010 23:59:59', '%m/%d/%Y %T')), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
--->  0
```

On version 5.0.51a-log, all work as expected:

```
SELECT '1999-04-01 23:34:12' > DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('09/06/2010 23:59:59', '%m/%d/%Y %T'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
--->  0  
SELECT '1999-04-01 23:34:12' > DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('09/06/2010 23:59:59', '%m/%d/%Y %T'), INTERVAL 720 HOUR);
--->  0
SELECT '1999-04-01 23:34:12' > DATE_SUB(TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('09/06/2010 23:59:59', '%m/%d/%Y %T')), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
--->  0
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE date_test`?

Comment: yes, it's a bug. See my post update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really strange and seems to be a bug.

I managed to boil it down to this:

```
SELECT  '0000-00-00 00:00:20' > STR_TO_DATE('10/06/2010 23:59:59', '%m/%d/%Y %T') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,
        '0000-00-00 00:00:21' > STR_TO_DATE('10/06/2010 23:59:59', '%m/%d/%Y %T') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

, which means that the year in the second expression gets compared to seconds in the first one.

There is probably some weird `DATE` to `INTEGER` cast in between.

Note that if you add `+ INTERVAL 0 SECONDS`, the expression gets casted into a proper `DATETIME` and works well.

I'll post it as a bug to `MySQL`.

**Update:**

This has already been submitted as a [**bug**](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56271) and a patch was released a week ago to fix it.